# Python namespace elements visibility (vs proper package structure)

Tags: python, pyramid, python-import

**Python3**

Tried to found an answer but failed. First I'll present the snippet, then I'll explain why I wanted to do it this way and what I wanted to achieve. Maybe it'll look like this approach is "the bad one".
Hence this semi-double topic, cause first I'd like to know why this snippet isn't working and second - I'd like to know if this approach is right.

So:

```
class Namespace:
    def some_function():
        pass

    class SomeClass:
        fcnt = some_function
```

This won't work due to:

`NameError: name 'some_function' is not defined`

What I want to achieve is code and file structure readability.

Above example is a snippet which I use (not this one, but it looks like this) in Pyramid project.

My project tree looks like this:

```
my_project
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_model.py
├── schemas
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── some_schema.py
│   └── some_other_schema.py
...
├── views
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_view.py
└── __init__.py
```

What I wanted to achieve is clean schema/model/view importing.

In **some_schema.py** file resides `class SomeSchema`, in **some_other_schema.py** `class SomeOtherSchema`.

With above snippet I can make:
`from my_project.schemas.some_schema import Schema`

and use it like `Schema.SomeSchema()`

I've got a little bit lost with packages and `import`s. How one could make a clean structure (one schema per file) and still be able to use Schema namespace? (In C++ I'd just put each of those classes in `Schema` namespace, that's why I did this in snippet above. But! What works in C++ maybe shouldn't be used in python, right?).

Thanks for answer in advance.

**EDIT:**
Ok, I've done some testing (I thought that I've done it, but looks like not..).

1. using `from my_project.schemas.some_schema import Schema` with another `from my_project.schemas.some_other_schema import Schema` causes in the second import shadowing first one. So if after first import I'd be able to use `x = Schema.SomeSchema()` than after second import I'd be unable to do this, because `class Schema` gets overriden. Right, so as Erik said - classes aren't namespaces. GOT IT!
2. in my very first snippet yes, I should've used `fnct = Namespace.some_function`. What's wierd - it works. I have the same statement in my pyramid code, with one difference. `some_function` has `@colander.deferred` decorator. In fact it looks like this:

   ```
   class Schema:
       @colander.deferred
       def deferred_some_function(node, kw):
           something  = kw.get("something", [])
           return deform.widget.SelectWidget(values=something,
                                         multiple=True)

       class SomeSchema(colander.MappingSchema):
           somethings  = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Set(),
                                         widget=Schema.deferred_some_function)
   ```

   And I get `NameError: name 'Schema' is not defined`
3. Getting back to package format. With this:

   ```
   ### another/file.py
   from foo.bar.schema import SomeSchema

   # do something with SomeSchema:
   smth = SomeSchema()
   smth.fcnt()
   ```

   I have to make one module `foo/bar/schema.py` in which I'd have to put all my `SomeXSchema` classes. An if I have lots of them, then there's the unreadabilty glitch which I wanted to get rid off by splitting SomeXSchema - one per file. Can I accomplish this somehow? I want to call this class for example: `User`. And here's the THING. Maybe I do it wrong? I'd like to have class named `User` in `schema` *namespace* and class named `User` in `model` *namespace*. Shouldn't I? Maybe I ought to use prefix? Like `class SchemaUser` and `class ModelUser` ? I wanted to avoid it by the use of modules/packages. 
   If I'd use : `import foo.bar.schema` then I'd have to use it like `x = foo.bar.schema.User()` right? There is no way to use it like `x = schema.User()` ? Sorry, I just got stuck, my brain got fixed. Maybe I need a little break to take a fresh look?

   **ANOTHER EDIT (FOR POINT 3 ONLY)**

   I did some more research. The answer here would be to make it like this:

   ```
   ## file: myproject/schemas/__init__.py
   from .some_schema import SomeSchema
   from .some_other_schema import SomeOtherSchema
   ```

   then usage would be like this:

   ```
   ## some file using it
   import myproject.schemas as schema
   s1 = schema.SomeSchema()
   s2 = schema.SomeOtherSchema()
   ```

   Would it be *lege artis*?
4. If anyone thinks that topic should be changed - go ahead, give me something more meaningful, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Executing the snippet gives me `NameError: name 'some_function' is not defined` and not the error you point out.

Comment: why are you making this more complicated that it needs to be? I've provided you with 2 alternative importing styles, one that can causes shadowing and one that doesn't. Also, please note that according to PEP8, module names should be `some_schema` or `someschema` but not `someSchema`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your edits.

Comment: Edited examples to be ok with PEP8. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: about your point 4.—topics should not be changed; the question title sets the topic and unless you edit the title and the question, the topic cannot be changed without going off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are swimming upstream by trying to do what you are trying to do.

Classes are meant for defining new data types not as a means to group related parts of code together. Modules are perfectly suited for that, and I presume you know that well because of the *"(vs proper package structure)"* part in the question title.

Modules can also be imported as objects, so to achieve what you want:

```
### foo/bar/schema.py
def some_function():
    pass
class SomeSchema:
    fcnt = some_function


### another/file.py
from foo.bar import schema

# do something with SomeSchema:
smth = schema.SomeSchema()
smth.fcnt()
```

...although it's also typical to import classes directly into the scope like this (i.e. being able to refer to `SomeSchema` after the import as opposed to `schema.SomeSchema`):

```
### another/file.py
from foo.bar.schema import SomeSchema

# do something with SomeSchema:
smth = SomeSchema()
smth.fcnt()
```

(Also note that module names should be lowercase as suggested by [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and only class names should use `PascalCase`)

This, by the way, applies to programming in general, not just Python. There are a few languages such as Java and C# which require that functions be declared inside of classes as statics because they disallow writing of code outside of classes for some weird reason, but even these languages have modules/proper namespaces for structuring your code; i.e. classes are not normally put inside other classes (they sometimes are, but for wholly different reasons/goals than yours).

So basically "class" means a "type" or "a set of objects having similar behavior"; once you ignore that principle/definition, you're writing bad code by definition.

**PS.** if you are using Python 2.x, you should be inheriting your classes from `object` so as to get [new-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) classes.

**PPS.** in any case, even technically speaking, what you are trying to do won't work cleanly in Python:

```
class fake_namespace:
    def some_function():
        pass
    class RealClass:
        some_function  # <-- that name is not even visibile here;
                       # you'd have to use fake_namespace.some_function instead
```

...and this is the reason for the exception I reported I was getting: NameError: name 'some_function' is not defined.

**EDIT AS PER YOUR EDITS:**

I'm not really sure why you're making it so complicated; also some of your statements are false:

> If I'd use : import foo.bar.schema then I'd have to use it like x = foo.bar.schema.User right?

No. Please learn how Python modules work.

> I'd like to have class named User in Schema namespace and class named User in Model namespace. Shouldn't I? Maybe I ought to use prefix? Like class SchemaUser and class ModelUser

please note that namespaces a.k.a. modules should be `lowercase` not `PascalCase`.

> An if I have lots of them, then there's the unreadabilty glitch which I wanted to get rid off by splitting SomeXSchema - one per file. Can I accomplish this somehow?

Yes; you can put your classes in individual submodules, e.g. `schema1/class1.py`, `schema/class2.py` etc; then you can "collect" them into `schema/__init__.py` so that you could import them directly from `schema`:

```
# schema/__init__.py
from .class1 import Class1
from .class2 import Class2

__all__ = [Class1, Class2]  # optional
```

**General note:** you can name your schema modules differently, e.g. `schema1`, `schema2`, etc; then you could just use them like this:

```
from somewhere import schema1
from somewhere_else import schema2

s1_user = schema1.User()
s2_user = schema2.User()
# etc
```

For more information on how Python modules work, refer to http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: 1. I know no other way to instantiate object of class SomeSchema residing in `foo/bar/schema.py` with this import: `import foo.bar.schema` than to do `x=foo.bar.schema.SomeSchema()`
2. PEP8 - fixing! Sorry.
3. So the idea which I wrote is ok (the one with `from .some_schema import SomeSchema`)

Comment: 1. did you miss my `from foo.bar import schema` and `from foo.bar.schema import SomeSchema`? 3. yes, why not.

Comment: 1. It was reply to yours "No. Please learn how Python modules work." where example was using EXACTLY this import : `import foo.bar.schema`. I haven't missed anything. So to get to the point with ABOVE import statement there is no other way to use it's contents than to `x=foo.bar.schema.SomeSchema()`.

3. great!

Answer (score 0):

### Name and binding

You can read [`Python naming and binding`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) and understand how Python namespace works.

A scope defines the visibility of a name within a block. If a local variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block. If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces a different binding for the name. `The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods this includes generator expressions since they are implemented using a function scope.`

BTW, use `globals()` and `locals()` can help debug for variable binding.

### The User Problem

You can try this instead:

```
from model import User as modelUser
from foo.bar.schema import User as schemaUser
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using `as` in this context (`from foo.bar.schema import User as schemaUser`). That's what namespaces are for, right? I might also be "polluted" by C++, and maybe that's the "Python's way"?

Comment: Yes. In fact, using assignment in module scope means adding a attribute to the module's `namespace`. And `from model import User as modelUser` almost equals `modelUser = model.User`, they both are assignment statement. You can feel free to use it.

Comment: That's the "Python's way" IMO. :-)

Comment: @Goat: only it should be `from model import User as ModelUser`—class names should be capitalized regardless of whether the name is the original name or an alias.